# Does anyone know how to get the theta under the arg max in this formula?

Tags: support, formatting

Was trying to reformat the formula in [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5177/please-explain-this-log-probability-function-what-does-each-part-mean), but can't get the theta to appear under the max.

[image]

I've been going through the formatting guide, but haven't yet identified how to do it without a fraction.  (In limit functions, the placement seems to be automatic.)  Wondering if there's a way to do this simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the source of this answer

$$\underset{\boldsymbol{\theta}}{\operatorname{argmax}}$$

Comment: beautiful!  appreciate the assist--saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @DukeZhou No problem. For this type of questions, have a look at: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). It also helps me a lot. Maybe you could also try a tool like: https://mathpix.com/. I've never tried it, but it might be really useful, if it works.